# How to add cookie to request for PHP/GD imagecreatefromJPEG?

Tags: php, gd

I'm using PHP GD to fetch an image from a remote server.
$res=imagecreatefromJPEG ($url);

I need to have a cookie set with a value along with the call to get the image.

Is this possible with GD?
How would I do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [stream_context_set_default](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-set-default.php) and the [header option](http://www.php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) to send a cookie header.